# Meaning of '0', and two apostrophes ' ' in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I'm trying to wrap my head around somebody else's query, and stepped into this:

```
SELECT '0' AS Interaction,
       a.name AS 'Serial_No',
       ' ' AS Questionnaire_ID,
```

and so on.

Any ideas on what does '0' and ' ' (empty space between two apostrophes) mean when it comes to column names in SQL SELECT?

Comment: They're literal strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns a result set where the first column is called `Interaction` and has the value `'0'` in all rows.  Note that this is a string value with a '0' character.

The second column is `Serial_no`, and the third is an empty string called `Questionaire_Id`.